# How Stripe confirm payment while they do not ask for first and last name?

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments

I have no experience with using stripe payment, I recently installed the WooCommerce plugin for stipe. In this plugin, there is no option for users to type their name and last name, and zip code (it seems to me successful payment must ask for this information). There are only inputs to type card number, CVC, expire date.

My question is that:

- How to add first name, last name, zip code input to validate the cardholder name and card number are identical, and they match.
- Without this information how is Stripe going to verify the payment?

I really appreciate your kindness, if you have experience using Stripe please share it with me.

Comment: I think this has less to do with programming, and more to do with understanding the complicated world of payments and payment authentication.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP I see many websites on the checkout page, ask for even address of the cardholder, how stripe do not ask for first and last name? I have a doubt that not receiving this information may cause a problem in payment or not? or will not affect the payment?

Comment: @IMSoP I read Stripe documents, in fact, it is not related to the complicated world of payment, they check the first name based on `billing_fitst_name` input, which user types in the delivery address section.

Comment: Your second bullet point is very much a question about the payment process: as Alex's answer says, the cardholder details are not required to make the transaction work, they're just commonly used as a layer of fraud prevention. That bullet also contains a misconception: Stripe doesn't verify any of the details, because they don't have anything to verify them against; only the issuing bank has the information to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The name and billing address (including zip code) are not required to complete a credit card payment. Generally speaking, you would only need the card number, expiry date and cvv to make a successful payment.
2. Other information collected are used to increase the "authentication" rates of the payment. The more information provided, the more likely that the bank will approve the transaction.
3. The information is also used to prevent fraud https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/prevention#collect-information